# jstreetable plugin: issue with width and context menus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jstree

I am trying to use jstree with the [jstreetable](https://github.com/adamjimenez/jstree-table) plugin, together with bootstrap. In particular I have a [bootstrap dropdown menu](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) that I want to include as html in one of the jstree table colons. The menu fails to open - see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plemdoux/p5jrw40w).

If the same dropdown menu is placed outside jstree, I can programmatically open/close it (code below also added to jsfiddle) :

```
<button onclick="$('#ContextMenuId2').slideToggle()">test open menu outside jstree</button>
<div id="ContextMenuOutsideJSTree">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="ContextMenuId2">
        <li class="dropdown messages-menu details" onclick="ShowPolicyDetails()"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>Policy Details</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown messages-menu"><a href=ManageMonitors.php><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>Disable this policy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The other issue I am facing in the same context is that I cannot set the colon width in the jstreetable plugin - the same jsfiddle can be used to highlight the  issue - no matter the value for column width, it seems to be ignored.

Thanks much for the help !

Answer (score 0):

It works. it stays behind jstree div. You need to enlarge jstree div height. Then you will see. And make y postion -10 of ContextMenuId. There is picture [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBIiV.png). I could only show a little bit. You have to work on it. You have to change node height also.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! However I tried to set the height to no avail : I tried '<div style="height:800px" id="PolicyTree">' but this did not change anything. Anything else I should look into ? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you again, will take a closer look at your suggestions.